# Windows 10- how do I ensure Python script will run as long as computer is on?

Tags: python, windows, windows-10

Unfortunately, I can't seem to use Windows Task Scheduler as I don't have admin rights on my work computer, and when I sign in as admin to run tasks the Python script doesn't run. Because of this, the only alternative I've found is creating a bash script that will run my .py file and adding that to my programs that run on startup.

This seems to work fine whenever I restart my computer, but I notice that if I leave my computer on overnight the batch script will close and my Python script won't run. I've checked the log files for any errors and there don't seem to be any issues in the script, it just seems that the cmd prompt screen closes.

Here is what I put in my .bat file:

```
"C:\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" "T:\service.py" > T:\output.log 2>&1

cmd /k
```

Just trying to figure out- why is this happening? And is there any way I can just keep this script running as long as my computer is on?

Comment: What if you keep it running in an infinite loop in your batch file wrapper? (I personally like vbscript wrappers for such tasks, because wscript.exe does not keep any window open in taskbar.)

Comment: The Python script is running in an infinite loop, so the script works fine as long as my bash file is open. It stays open all day during work, but for some reason if I leave my computer on overnight the bash file closes. Is that what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to create a Windows Service with PowerShell. Just have it automatically recover when it's terminated. See this as a reference.

https://github.com/yaplex/CodeSamples/blob/092159a847e330778494ea7b69ee84d120db7e36/PowerShell/Install-Windows-Service.ps1

Then you can monitor trends with Event Viewer as to why and when it's terminated.

Comment: Thanks- is there documentation on how to implement? So would I name my python script as the service in this code?

Comment: Just assign the $serviceName something descriptive to you.  I'm rusty on my Windows, but give that whirl.
# creating credentials which can be used to run my Windows service
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "YOURWINDOWSPASSWORS" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (".\MyUserName", $secpasswd)
$binaryPath = "C:\Python\Python37-32\python.exe T:\service.py".

Comment: Here is the reference, also I updated the link to a pull request that had edits.  https://yaplex.com/blog/create-a-windows-service-using-powershell

Comment: okay thanks for that- so I replicated that code exactly, replaced the username and password with my account info, and changed the binary path to my bash command with the instructions ("T:\service.py"). I opened the file in powershell and then powershell immediately closed. I don't think it worked as I don't see my outputs or logs refreshing- how can I check/troubleshoot? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Try providing your credentials as per the guide with the pop-up. Don't forget the DOMAIN\Username if it's not a local user account. Also, do you see the new service created in Start -> Run -> services.msc ?

Comment: I also tried the Get-Credential, signed in manually and it immediately closed. Also I don't see it on the Services page and can see that the code isn't running (no log files updating)

Comment: After typing in manually, seems like it is an access is denied error..... Do you know of any other solutions? If I created this service with admin rights do you think the service would always run on my computer? So I can just ask the team admin to run powershell as admin and create this service? Or would the service only last until I turn off my computer?